Plastic Bag price returns 0.4 when it should be 0.5 Java code
My issue is that I am inputting 0.2 as tax and 40.0 (length) * 10.0 (width) within the if statement would make the price 0.3. price = price + tax should be 0.5 yet I keep getting 0.4 why? Complete beginner and any help appreciated, I use Eclipse IDE.
here is my driver class:
package Bag;

public class Driver {
    
    //what is main method for? explain content
    //todo auto gen method stub
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        plasticBag plasticBag = new plasticBag();
        plasticBag.setLength(40.0);
        plasticBag.setWidth(10.0);
        plasticBag.setTax(0.2);
        System.out.println(plasticBag.getTax());
        System.out.print(plasticBag.getPrice());
        
        
        
        
    }

}

here is the plastic bag class:
package Bag;

public class plasticBag extends Bag {

    //instance variable specific to plastic 
    
    private double tax;
    
    public void setTax(double tax) {
        
        this.tax = tax;
        
    }
    
    public double getTax() {
        
        return tax;
        
        //why seperate setter and getter?
    }
    
    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        
        //what if I don't implement abstract methods?
        
        double area = getLength() * getWidth();
        if (area > 250.0) {price = 0.30;}
        else {price = 0.20;}
        return price + tax;
        // why are we getting price 0.4 not 0.5
    }
    

}

here is the bag abstract class
package Bag;

public abstract class Bag {
    
    private double length;
    private double width;
    // subclass can access price directly 
    protected double price; 
    
    public double getLength() {
        
        return length;
        
    }
    
    public void setLength(double length) {
        
        this.length = length;
        
        //which is the class level and which is the local?
        
    }
    
    public double getWidth() {
        
        return width;
        
    }
    
    public void setWidth(double with) {
        
        this.width = width;
        
    }
    
    //abstract method
    
    public abstract double getPrice();


}

I tried checking all data types, they all all double not int, so this shouldn't be a problem

You have a typo: public void setWidth(double with) Look at that and the lines directly below that

Just as a hint: Classes in Java always start with an uppercase letter by convention.

And package names are lower case

As g00se pointed out you spelled "width" wrong. public void setWidth(double with) {  Aside: this is the sort of error that a debugger would find pretty quickly.  Did you use one?  Do you  know how?

btw, even when you've fixed your typo, you still have a weakness in your code, which you might fix with something like if (width < PlasticBag.MIN_WIDTH) { throw new RuntimeException("Bag width less than " + PlasticBag.MIN_WIDTH); } Similar for length

Did you get a compiler warning that Variable with is unused ? If the compiler did give that warning, what did you do about it?  If the compiler didn't give that warning, maybe you should check to see if it has been disabled.

Big thank you everyone, absolute beginner been programming for 3 months so these comments have been invaluable. Issue is solved

The setWidth()-method has a bug.
public void setWidth(double with) {
    this.width = width;     
}

This will set the width-field to the value of itself (no change).
Recall, a unassigned variable of type double will default to 0.
(Unassigned, meaning: private double width;)
So, in the getPrice()-method, the calculated area will not be the expected 400, but actually: 40 * 0. This will enter the else-branch, thus returning the final result of 0.4.
